# Make iframe content non-responsive

Tags: html, iframe

So I'm making a grid with iframes in it. What I'm getting now is this:
[image]

As you can see, the website adjusts to the size of the iframe. What I want, is that the content will shrink to the size of the iframe, without using their responsive design. I don't have much experience with iframes, I hope there's someone here that can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. The content of the iframe is controlled by the external website.

Comment: how many times do i have to untag php from non-php related questions...

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be done with Iframes -- The only real option you have is to take a screen shot of the website in a  full size browser, and then serve a scaled image of the site.

This can either be done

- when the user otherwise opens the website, and the scale down those images to the size you want

  That is what google-chrome does for the short-cut page.
- or server side, create a virtual browser and render the page server side, then take a screen shot of the virtual browser.

  That is what some search engines have done in the past, where they offered a miniture view of the website for a search result before visiting (I however don't think any search engines currently offers this feature)